# vb.net next and previous row with many datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, row

I have two datagridviews, namely **DataGV1** and **DataGV2**... when I click the next button, on DataGV1, it runs as desired... and so on until the last row in DataGV1... and click the next button next to read the row on DataGV2.. . but he didn't take row index 0, he read into the second row in DataGV2...

```
Private Sub NextBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NextBtn.Click...
    
    ...Dim lrData1 As Integer = DataGV1.Rows.Count - 1, lrData2 As Integer = ...DataGV2.Rows.Count - 1...
    ...Dim a As Integer, price As Decimal, lr As Integer = lrData1 + lrData2...
    ...Dim row1 As Integer, row2 As Integer...
    
    ...a = rowDataTXT.Text...
    ...If a >= 0 And a < lrData1 Then...
       ...If DataGV1.CurrentCell.Selected = False Then...
           ...DataGV1.CurrentCell.Selected = True...
           ...row1 = DataGV1.SelectedRows(0).Index...
           ...a = -1...
       ...Else...
           ...row1 = DataGV1.SelectedRows(0).Index + 1...
       ...End If...**

        If row1 <= DataGV1.Rows.Count - 2 Then
           Dim nextRow As DataGridViewRow = DataGV1.Rows(row1 )
           DataGV1.CurrentCell = nextRow.Cells(0)
           DataGV1.Rows(row1 ).Selected = True
       End If
        
       Dim i As Integer = DataGV1.SelectedRows(0).Index
       If i >= 0 AndAlso i < DataGV1.Rows.Count - 1 Then
           itemTxt.Text = DataGV1(0, i).Value.ToString
           stokAlreadyTXT.Text = DataGV1(1, i).Value.ToString
           priceTXT.Text = DataGV1(2, i).Value.ToString
           price = DataGV1(2, i).Value                
       End If
       a += 1
    End If
        
    If a >= lrData1And a < lrData1 + lrData2 Then
       DataGV1.CurrentRow.Selected = False
       Me.TabControl1.SelectedTab = TabPage2
    
       If a = lrData1 Then
           DataGV2.Rows(0).Selected = True
           row2 = DataGV2.SelectedRows(0).Index
       Else
           a = lrData2 
           row2 = DataGV2.SelectedRows(0).Index + 1
       End If
        
       If row2 <= DataGV2.Rows.Count - 2 Then
           Dim nextRow As DataGridViewRow = DataGV2.Rows(row2 )
           DataGV2.CurrentCell = nextRow.Cells(0)
           DataGV2.Rows(row2 ).Selected = True
       End If
        
       Dim i As Integer = DataGV2.SelectedRows(0).Index
       If i >= 0 AndAlso i < DataGV2.Rows.Count - 1 Then
           itemTxt.Text = DataGV2(0, i).Value.ToString
           stokAlreadyTXT.Text = DataGV2(1, i).Value.ToString
           priceTXT.Text = DataGV2(2, i).Value.ToString
           price = DataGV2(2, i).Value
       End If
       a += row2
     End If
     rowDataTXT.Text = a
     End Sub
        
     Private Sub backBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles backBtn.Click
        Dim lrData1 As Integer = DataGV1.Rows.Count - 1, lrData2 As Integer = DataGV2.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim a As Integer, price As Decimal, lr As Integer = lrData1 + lrData2, row2 As Integer, row1 As Integer
        
        a = rowDataTXT.Text
        If a >= 0 And a <= lrData1 Then
              TabControl1.SelectedTab = TabPage1
               If DataGV1.CurrentCell.Selected = False Then
                        DataGV1.CurrentCell.Selected = True
                        row1 = DataGV1.SelectedRows(0).Index + lrData1 
               Else
                        row1 = DataGV1.SelectedRows(0).Index - 1
               End If
    
               If row1 >= 0 And row1 <= DataGV1.Rows.Count - 2 Then
                        Dim nextRow As DataGridViewRow = DataGV1.Rows(row1 )
                        DataGV1.CurrentCell = nextRow.Cells(0)
                        DataGV1.Rows(row1 ).Selected = True
               End If
        
               Dim i As Integer = DataGV1.SelectedRows(0).Index
               If i >= 0 AndAlso i < DataGV1.Rows.Count - 1 Then
                        itemTxt.Text = DataGV1(0, i).Value.ToString
                        stokAlreadyTXT.Text = DataGV1(1, i).Value.ToString
                        priceTXT.Text = DataGV1(2, i).Value.ToString
                        price = DataGV1(2, i).Value                
               End If
               a -= 1
         End If
        
         If a > lrData1 And a <= lrData1 + lrData2 Then
               Me.TabControl1.SelectedTab = TabPage2
               row2 = DataGV2.SelectedRows(0).Index - 1
               If row2 >= 0 And row2 <= DataGV2.Rows.Count - 2 Then
               Dim nextRow As DataGridViewRow = DataGV2.Rows(row2 )
               DataGV2.CurrentCell = nextRow.Cells(0)
               DataGV2.Rows(row2 ).Selected = True
         End If
        
         Dim i As Integer = DataGV2.SelectedRows(0).Index
         If i >= 0 AndAlso i < DataGV2.Rows.Count - 1 Then
                 itemTxt.Text = DataGV2(0, i).Value.ToString
                 stokAlreadyTXT.Text = DataGV2(1, i).Value.ToString
                 priceTXT.Text = DataGV2(2, i).Value.ToString
                 price = DataGV2(2, i).Value                
         End If
                 a -= 1
      End If
      rowDataTXT.Text = a
        
    End Sub
```

Comment: Post the actual code. Post at least a complete Sub/Function. Try to describe your expected results a bit better. Look into the `DataBoundItem` property of the `SelectedRows()` collection; it is easier to work with than trying to keep track of indexes.